# Jekyll won't build if gemfile exists

Tags: github, bundler, jekyll, github-pages

I'm working on my Github Pages site, so need to build it on my local machine. [Following their instructions](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-your-github-pages-site-locally-with-jekyll/), I have set it up using bundler. However bundler appears to break the Jekyll build.

If I run `jekyll new NewSite` it creates a new site that can be built using `jekyll serve`. As soon as I run `bundle install`, or `bundle update`, however, Jekyll refuses to run, giving the below error on the "generating" step.

```
jekyll 3.0.5 | Error:  No such file or directory - git remote --verbose
```

It will then give that same error every time either `bundle exec jekyll serve` or `jekyll serve` are called. Further investigation has found that the error goes away if the gemfile file is deleted.

What have I misconfigured?

### Update:

1. I've added a stack trace as requested
2. I realised it was the gemfile itself that was causing the issue, not the gemfile.lock
3. Problem turned out to have nothing to do with Windows, so removed references to it

---

Stack trace:

```
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-github-metadata-1.11.1/lib/jekyll-github-metadata/ghp_metadata_generator.rb:32
:in ``': No such file or directory - git remote --verbose (Errno::ENOENT)
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-github-metadata-1.11.1/lib/jekyll-github-metadata/ghp_metadata_generator.rb:32:in `git_remote_url'
from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-github-metadata-1.11.1/lib/jekyll-github-metadata/ghp_metadata_generator.rb:39:in `nwo_from_git_origin_remote'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-github-metadata-1.11.1/lib/jekyll-github-metadata/ghp_metadata_generator.rb:65:in `nwo'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-github-metadata-1.11.1/lib/jekyll-github-metadata/ghp_metadata_generator.rb:8:in `generate'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.0.5/lib/jekyll/site.rb:154:in `block in generate'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.0.5/lib/jekyll/site.rb:153:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.0.5/lib/jekyll/site.rb:153:in `generate'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.0.5/lib/jekyll/site.rb:58:in `process'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.0.5/lib/jekyll/command.rb:28:in `process_site'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.0.5/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:60:in `build'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.0.5/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:35:in `process'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.0.5/lib/jekyll/commands/serve.rb:26:in `block (2 levels) in init_with_program'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `call'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `block in execute'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `execute'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/program.rb:42:in `go'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary.rb:19:in `program'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.0.5/bin/jekyll:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby22/bin/jekyll:23:in `load'
    from C:/Ruby22/bin/jekyll:23:in `<main>'
```

---

My Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'github-pages', group: :jekyll_plugins
gem 'safe_yaml', '~> 1.0.4'
gem 'wdm', '~> 0.1.0' if Gem.win_platform?
```

Ruby version: 2.2.4 32 bit

Bundler version: 1.12.3

Jekyll Version: 3.0.5

Comment: Can you post a error with a trace `bundle exec jekyll serve --trace`.

Comment: @DavidJacquel Done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is `jekyll-github-metadata` gem which is bugging when trying to run a `git remote --verbose` command on your system ([code](https://github.com/jekyll/github-metadata/blob/master/lib/jekyll-github-metadata/ghp_metadata_generator.rb#L32)).

You can try to set a `_config.yml` variable ([documentation](https://github.com/jekyll/github-metadata#usage)) :

```
repository: username/repo-name
```